# Using AJAX to navigate between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've implemented a JS solution to navigate between pages but now, I realize that's not enought for my needs.

I'd like to navigate between pages using AJAX, and my first idea was this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //initial
    $('#main').load('content/index.php');

    //M. clicks
    $('.menu_pc li a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#main').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Where `#main` it's the ID of the HTML section.

What happen if I use this method? Well, that I'm kind of limited because I should handle every click using the same method and I'm not sure if it will even work or not (first time using this).

For instance, if I have to recharge the header after some login from a user showing him his own name, I probably have problems using that method. That's why I need to use some REAL AJAX code.

Like replace this form for a welcome message like "Hello *user*".

[image]

Some hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider using angular or emberjs if you want ot create single page website.

Comment: I will check it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method. But it depends on what is your purpose? If you want to create very simple website with several pages it will be ok.

But if you plan to create something bigger, it will be hardly scalable if you will do it that way.

So if your purpose is to create a big and easily scalable website, then consider using for example angular or emberjs.

Comment: It will be a shop, so it's better to build something easy to scale, just in case.
Is angular the best option that I have to do that? What about to use ajax, like xmlhttprequest?

Comment: Angular is good technology for this purpose. It's very popular so you will easily find answers for your questions about it. Also it uses ajax technology  to communicate with server. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's just that I don't know how to begin. I'm gonna look up about this technology.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //initial
  $('#main').load('content/index.php');

  //M. clicks
  $('.menu_pc li a').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var redirectUrlPath = 'content/' + page;
    window.location.pathname = redirectUrlPath;
    return false;
  });
});
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but this will redirect you to a different page. Assuming your A tag looks something like this:

```
<a href='myNewPage'>link1</a>
```

Comment: This code plus the other that I posted? Or it's just enough with this one? Where is the event handler?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I will try that, anyway i think that I'm going to angular.